# Define an alias in fish shell

Tags: linux, shell, fish

I would like to define some aliases in fish. Apparently it should be possible to define them in

```
~/.config/fish/functions
```

but they don't get auto loaded when I restart the shell. Any ideas?

Comment: The answer down below with only a couple votes is, in my opinion correct. Autoloading in ./config/fish/functions only seems to work if there is one function per file.

Answer (score 501, accepted):

Just use `alias`. Here's a basic example:

```
# Define alias in shell
alias rmi "rm -i"

# Define alias in config file ( `~/.config/fish/config.fish` )
alias rmi="rm -i"

# This is equivalent to entering the following function:
function rmi
    rm -i $argv
end

# Then, to save it across terminal sessions:
funcsave rmi

# or, since Fish 3.0, define and save all at once:
alias --save rmi="rm -i"
```

The command `funcsave` creates the file `~/.config/fish/functions/rmi.fish`.  This is handled automatically when using the newer `alias --save` syntax.

More info about Fish aliases can be found in [the official manual](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#alias).

Comment: Also note that in fish an alias is just a shellscript wrapper around a function.

Comment: @user456584 ...and that's to bad, because you can't do `alias local "set -l"` ;-(

Comment: Just a note of which file to put this in. I put mine in `~/.config/fish/config.fish` so it loads every time I run a terminal.

Comment: Don't we need to quote `"$argv"` to handle arguments with spaces like we do with bash `"$@"`?

Comment: @kyb, nope, fish is smarter than bash like that. Actually, ALL variables in fish are arrays. Go to [Shell variables](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#variables) and scroll down to the Arrays subsection

Comment: Try this in an interactive fish session: `set v foo bar "baz quz"; printf '%s\n' $v; printf '%s\n' "$v"`, and also experiment with the `--show` option for `set`.

Comment: Just don't forget to `source .config/fish/config.fish` – otherwise you will scratch your head and wonder why fish seemingly ignores the alias you just set.

Comment: In case anyone is stupid like me: `alias a = "b"` doesn't work, you need to leave out the spaces

Answer (score 129):

This is how I define a new function `foo`, run it, and save it persistently.

```
sthorne@pearl~> function foo
                    echo 'foo was here'
                end
sthorne@pearl~> foo
foo was here
sthorne@pearl~> funcsave foo
```

Comment: Thanks Jerub. For some reason after funcsave it gave me an error:
troff: fatal error: can't open `/usr/share/fish/man/save_function.1': No such file or directory

Comment: You can also edit functions using `funced`. E.g. `funced foo`.

Comment: Running `funcsave {some_function_name}` will save it in `~/.config/fish/functions/{some_function_name}.fish`

Comment: I save the grep function so that it use ```rg``` instead. But when I use ```grep --version``` command, it didn't give an output similar to ```rg --version```. Why?! @Hjulle

Comment: @Pranav Is the sequence of commands you ran: `alias grep=rg`, `funcsave grep` and `grep --version`?

Comment: @Hjulle yes I did. For now, I have edited the config.fish file as mentioned in the solution below. And it worked. I now can do ```grep --version``` and see the result of ```rg --version```.

Answer (score 66):

For posterity, fish aliases are just functions:

```
$ alias foo="echo bar"
$ type foo
foo is a function with definition
function foo
    echo bar $argv; 
end
```

To remove it

```
$ unalias foo
/usr/bin/unalias: line 2: unalias: foo: not found
$ functions -e foo
$ type foo
type: Could not find “foo”
```

Comment: After you create the function, you can do `funcsave foo`. This will save the function into `~/.config/fish/functions/foo.fish`, where fish will automatically load it the first time it is called from a new session.

Comment: `alias foo="echo bar"` was by far the easiest solution

Comment: unalias is not available in fish 3.2.0

Comment: It's never been available in fish. That's why I demonstrate that it throws an error.

Answer (score 34):

If you add an `abbr` instead of an `alias` you'll get better auto-complete. In fish `abbr` more closely matches the behavior of a bash alias.

```sh
abbr -a gco "git checkout"
```

Will `-a`dd a new `abbr`eviation `gco` that expands to `git checkout`.

[Here's a video demo of the resulting auto-complete features](https://streamable.com/s/acbmz/qfqikt)

Answer (score 28):

fish starts by executing commands in ~/.config/fish/config.fish.
You can create it if it does not exist:

> vim ~/.config/fish/config.fish

and save it with `:wq`

step1. make configuration file (like .bashrc)

> config.fish

step2. just write your alias like this;

> alias rm="rm -i"

Comment: writing inside fish config worked for me. I wonder why the fish function didn't gave me the expected results.

Answer (score 25):

I know there are 11 answers already at this point, and *they all work*, but *most* are also suboptimal in 2022 (and for the past few years).

##### Short, updated, current answer for all releases since [3.0b1](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/relnotes.html#fish-3-0b1-released-december-11-2018):

- The quickest and best way to do what is requested in this question is:

  ```sh
  alias -s <aliasname> "command(s)" # Or --save
  ```

  ***Important***: *Simply do this one time per alias at the command-line.  Do not add it to your startup config.*
- To list existing aliases which have been defined this way (since [fish 2.5b1](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/relnotes.html#fish-2-5b1-released-january-14-2017)):

  ```sh
  alias
  ```
- To edit an alias created this way:

  ```sh
  funced -s <aliasname> # or --save
  ```
- To remove an alias defined this way (since [fish 3.4.0](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/relnotes.html#fish-3-4-0-released-march-12-2022)):

  ```sh
  functions -e <aliasname> # or --erase
  funcsave <aliasname>
  ```

  Note that since 3.4.0 was only released a few weeks ago, I'll include the commands that work in previous versions as well:

  ```sh
  functions -e <aliasname> # or --erase
  rm ~/.config/fish/functions/<aliasname>.fish
  ```

  Ironically, you may even want to alias this into `unalias`.  You'll need to first `alias -s unalias` the `functions -e ...` part, then `funced -s unalias` again to add the `rm ...`.

---

Note that [@nemanja's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66676057/11810933) does include the `alias -s` command, but doesn't go into much detail.  Regardless, since it predates mine, I wouldn't mind at all if it was the accepted answer.  However, the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2763014/11810933) is a bit outdated.  While it could, in theory, be edited, the necessary changes, IMHO, would create a *different* answer, which we aren't supposed to do.

While [@nemanja's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66676057/11810933) is the best solution for current fish releases, I'm writing this as a separate answer to:

- Go into more detail on *why* ('alias -s`) is the best solution.
- Go into more detail on why the other answers are suboptimal with current fish releases.
- Provide the additional information on editing and removing aliases which are defined this way.

---

##### Much more detail on why the above is preferred over the other answers

First, it is important to understand that, as Glenn Jackman (a former fish shell contributor) mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22538401/11810933), the `alias` command in fish is just syntactic sugar for creating a function.

However, when you define an alias this way, it is defined *only in memory*.  It is not persisted.  That ability was added shortly after that answer was written.

###### Outdated method #1

With that in mind, the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2763014/11810933) from 2010 has a few issues nowadays.

First, you really *shouldn't* define your aliases in your config.  That may have been correct in 2010, but even then I think fish supported lazy-loading of functions/aliases, which is a better option.  Defining functions/aliases in your startup config is the "bash/zsh way".  Fish is better than that ...

One of the (many) features that sets fish apart from bash and zsh is lazy-loading.  Lazy is *good* in this case.  You *want* lazy-loading.  You *need* lazy-loading (ok, well maybe not *need*), but anyway ...

As the original question mentioned, it *is* possible to define your functions in `~/.config/fish/functions/`, although it is a *directory* rather than a *file*.  Note that this will be `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fish/functions` if that variable is defined.

Functions in this directory are lazy-loaded.

Lazy loading means:

- Fish does *not* load any part of your alias/function when it starts.  This can speed up launch times significantly, especially if you have many aliases and/or complex functions, or perhaps are running on a slower system/VM/shared CPU host.
- No part of the function other than the name (for lookup purposes) is loaded into memory until it is used.
- The first time you call a function with `functionname`, then and only then will fish lazy-load the function from `~/.config/fish/functions/<functionname.fish>`.

How much of a difference this will make will depend on a lot of factors, but personally, I keep a lookout for simple ways to optimize my configuration.  One of the main factors that drove me from Zsh to fish was the increasingly slow startup of my Zsh config as I added features, functions, etc.  We've made the switch to a better shell (in our opinion, I assume) -- Why not take advantage of its improved features?

This lazy-loading *might* sound complicated, but it's almost exactly what the `alias -s` command does for us *without any additional effort*.

In addition, the `alias` command, goes several steps further and automatically adds a `--wraps <original_command>` argument to your function so that you get the added benefit of completions.  It also adds a `--description`, which is used to describe the function as an "alias".  As a result, running just:

```
alias
```

... by itself will give you a list of all functions/aliases defined this way.

###### Other answers

[Three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43994337/11810933) [separate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7620638/11810933) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65056686/11810933) also all mention using `~/.config.fish/config.fish`, either with `function` declarations or `alias` commands.

As with the original answer, this is the suboptimal, bash/zsh way of doing things.  This means that your aliases/functions will be processed and loaded every time you start a new shell.

I recommend that you take advantage of lazy-loading instead.

###### `mkalias` function

[This answer by @Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43830571/11810933) defines a `mkalias` function that creates *and* saves the alias.  A *very* good solution at the time (and IMHO should have had more upvotes), but it predated fish release 3.0 which added `alias --save/-s`, which now does the same thing.

###### `abbr` command

[@TobiasMühl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55369624/11810933) recommends using the `abbr` command, which is a reasonable alternative.  However, note that `alias` *does* handle completions, and in pretty much the same manner as the `abbr` example given in that answer.

```
alias -s gco "git checkout"
```

And completions will be based on `git checkout`, just as if it were an expanded abbreviation.

There *may* be some cases where the completions will be more accurate because abbreviations are expanded as soon as the <kbd>Space</kbd> is pressed after typing the abbreviation name.

That's one of the fundamental differences between abbreviations and aliases in fish.  Abbreviations are expanded at the prompt; aliases are not.

Another difference is that abbreviations are stored in variables, which *are* processed/loaded at shell startup (whether universal or global/config).  As mentioned above, aliases are lazy-loaded.

And yet another difference is that aliases, since they are functions, can be much more complex.  For instance, I have my `ls` set to be `exa` with the output piped to `bat`.  It's just not possible define that in an abbreviation.

That said, again, abbreviations are a feature to consider using in fish.  I do plan to shift a few of my aliases to abbreviations, since I have some where I want to *change* the arguments after expansion; something that's not possible with the unexpanded aliases.

Comment: which file is for define fish alias?

Comment: @SL5net Apologies - I don't understand the context of your question.  Can you rephrase it?  Thanks!

Comment: now i expect a good answer is for example : `~/.config/fish/config.fish`  is a good place to config fish

Comment: @SL5net That's covered (fairly extensively, I believe ) in my answer.  You *shouldn't* define them *in a file*.  You should define them *at the command line* using `alias -s <aliasname> "command(s)"`, *one time*.  That will create a corresponding function for each alias in `~/.config/fish/functions` that will be lazy-loaded on demand.

Comment: What if I want to copy my aliases into another machine ?
Should I copy the whole ~/.config/fish/functions directory instead of one simple configuration file ?

Comment: @DimitriLesnoff Either way, but yes, I maintain my functions directory in a git repository so that it's easy to keep in sync between multiple systems.  You could also maintain a single file that you transfer that *creates* the aliases via multiple `alias --save ...` commands.  Keeping them all in one file *works*, but as mentioned above, they are all loaded at startup in that case.

Answer (score 16):

Save your files as **`~/.config/fish/functions/{some_function_name}.fish`** and they should get autoloaded when you start fish.

Comment: Actually, they don't get "autoloaded" when you start fish.  They are "lazy loaded" on first use.  In other words, they do *nothing* until you call `{some_function_name}` the first time in a given shell.  At that point, fish searches the function path for `{some_function_name}.fish`, loads the function (which must *also* be named `{some_function_name}` from it, then executes it.  I'm not sure if this is a change in behavior since the answer was originally written, but I think it's always worked that way.

Answer (score 15):

1. if there is not **config.fish** in **~/.config/fish/**, make it.
2. there you can write your function .`function name; command; end`

Answer (score 13):

To properly load functions from **~/.config/fish/functions**

You may set only *ONE* function inside file and name file the same as function name + add .fish extension.

This way changing file contents reload functions in opened terminals (note some delay may occur ~1-5s)

That way if you edit either by commandline

```
function name; function_content; end
```

then

```
funcsave name
```

you have user defined functions in console and custom made in the same order.

Answer (score 7):

@bozhidar-batsov gave an absolutely complete answer that helps one understand the inner workings of the alias/function in fish. Reading fish documentation for an alias, there is also a `-s` flag that is really convenient to use, but I didn't see anyone mention it.

> -s or --save Automatically save the function created by the alias into your fish configuration directory using funcsave.

One-line solution for defining and saving an alias (for example):
`alias cl 'clear' -s`. Instantly works across all sessions and is persisted.

Navigate to the `~/.config/fish/functions/` and you'll see `cl.fish` file.

```sh
# Defined via `source`
function cl --wraps=clear --description 'alias cl clear'
  clear $argv;
end
```

Answer (score 5):

make a function in ~/.config/fish/functions called mkalias.fish and put this in

```
function mkalias --argument key value
  echo alias $key=$value
  alias $key=$value
  funcsave $key
end
```

and this will create aliases automatically.

Answer (score 4):

I found the prior answers and comments to be needlessly incomplete and/or confusing. The minimum that I needed to do was:

1. Create `~/.config/fish/config.fish`. This file can optionally be a softlink.
2. Add to it the line `alias myalias echo foo bar`.
3. Restart `fish`. To confirm the definition, try `type myalias`. Try the alias.